# Recovering deleted data from Debian WSL2 after rm -r ~

Tags: debian, data-recovery, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have accidentally deleted all my data from WSL2 using `rm -r ~` is there any way I can recover it? Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Usually, one would restore the accidentally deleted data from a recent backup.